# How to create unix process binary trees?

Tags: c, unix, process, fork

Can some one help me out here, not necessarily complete my homework.

I need to create a process tree using fork(); in Unix/C so far the best I can get to to the 4th level here is my code:

```
/* Includes */
#include <unistd.h> /* Symbolic Constants */
#include <stdio.h> /* Input/Output */
#include <stdlib.h> /* General Utilities */

int main()
{
    pid_t childpid;
    pid_t pid;
    int i;
    childpid=fork();
    waitpid();
    i=0;
    for (; i<1; i++) {
        int b=0;
        for (; b<1;b++) {
            childpid=fork();
            fprintf(stderr,"the value of i is %d, i am %ld , my parent is %ld\n",
                            i, (long)getpid(), (long)getppid());

            if (childpid==0) {
                break;
            }

        }
        if (childpid==0) {
            break;
        }
    }

    sleep(1);
}
```

I am very new to C programming, well programming in general, so I wanted to ask the general public what steps I am missing. The tree depth needs to be user specified so I figured I would use n a for loop but that only multiplies across a level rather than creating new levels.

Can someone help me out and point me in the right direction :)
I need it to fork like this

```
           i
          / \
         /   \
        /     \
       /       \
      /         \
     i           i
    / \         / \
   /   \       /   \
  i     i     i     i
 / \   / \   / \   / \
i   i i   i i   i i   i
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`waitpid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/waitpid.html) function requires arguments.

The initial `childpid = fork();` is unexpected.

You can sensibly write:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
```

for the loops unless you insist on using C89 instead of C99 syntax.

### Attempt 2

#### Example output

```
Start 46480
i am 46480, my parent is 30775
i am 46482, my parent is 46480
i am 46481, my parent is 46480
i am 46483, my parent is 46481
i am 46484, my parent is 46482
i am 46486, my parent is 46482
i am 46487, my parent is 46483
Exit 46487
i am 46488, my parent is 46484
Exit 46488
i am 46485, my parent is 46481
i am 46491, my parent is 46484
Exit 46491
i am 46489, my parent is 46483
Exit 46489
Exit 46483
i am 46492, my parent is 46486
Exit 46492
Exit 46484
i am 46490, my parent is 46486
Exit 46490
i am 46493, my parent is 46485
Exit 46493
Exit 46486
Exit 46482
i am 46494, my parent is 46485
Exit 46494
Exit 46485
Exit 46481
Exit 46480
```

#### Example source

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

static pid_t fork_ok(void)
{
    pid_t pid;
    if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fork failure in pid %d\n", (int)getpid());
        exit(1);
    }
    return pid;
}

int main(void)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Start %d\n", (int)getpid());

    for (int level = 0; level < 3; level++)
    {
        if (fork_ok() == 0 || fork_ok() == 0)
            continue;
        break;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "i am %d, my parent is %d\n",
            (int)getpid(), (int)getppid());
    while (wait(0) > 0)
        ;
    fprintf(stderr, "Exit %d\n", (int)getpid());
    return(0);
}
```

This uses a loop, a somewhat unusual loop.  At each level, the parent process forks two children; the children each 'continue' to the next level, while the parent is done and exits the loop.  The clean up code is the same as before (see below).

#### Recursive variant

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

static pid_t fork_ok(void)
{
    pid_t pid;
    if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fork failure in pid %d\n", (int)getpid());
        exit(1);
    }
    return pid;
}

static void new_level(int level)
{
    if (level > 3)
        return;
    if (fork_ok() == 0 || fork_ok() == 0)
        new_level(level+1);
    else
    {
        printf("i am %d, my parent is %d\n",
                (int)getpid(), (int)getppid());
        while (wait(0) > 0)
            ;
        printf("Exit %d\n", (int)getpid());
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("Start %d\n", (int)getpid());
    fflush(0);
    new_level(0);
    return(0);
}
```

---

### Attempt 1

I'm not convinced you need any loops.  This seemed to do the trick for me:

#### Example output

```
Start 44397
i am 44397, my parent is 30775
i am 44400, my parent is 44397
i am 44401, my parent is 44397
Exit 44401
i am 44399, my parent is 44397
i am 44398, my parent is 44397
i am 44404, my parent is 44400
Exit 44404
i am 44403, my parent is 44399
i am 44402, my parent is 44398
i am 44405, my parent is 44398
i am 44407, my parent is 44398
Exit 44407
Exit 44400
i am 44406, my parent is 44399
Exit 44406
i am 44408, my parent is 44402
i am 44410, my parent is 44402
i am 44411, my parent is 44405
Exit 44410
Exit 44411
i am 44409, my parent is 44403
Exit 44409
Exit 44405
i am 44412, my parent is 44408
Exit 44412
Exit 44403
Exit 44399
Exit 44408
Exit 44402
Exit 44398
Exit 44397
```

#### Source Code

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(void)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Start %d\n", (int)getpid());
    if (fork() < 0 || fork() < 0 || fork() < 0 || fork() < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fork failure in pid %d\n", (int)getpid());
        exit(1);
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "i am %d, my parent is %d\n",
            (int)getpid(), (int)getppid());
    while (wait(0) > 0)
        ;
    fprintf(stderr, "Exit %d\n", (int)getpid());
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: thats for helping, I am actually not sure what is happening in your code. It also does not fork the way I was looking for it and the modifications I have tried just failed :/

Comment: Thanks! that second attempt makes a lot more sense because of the loop. I can actually see where everything is coming from. What exactly keeps creating process in the first example? This has been the most confusing concept to grasp lol

Comment: Yeah - it is confusing.  It is moderately weird requirement, the sort of thing sadistic teaching staff devise for innocent suckers^H^H^H^H^H^H^Hstudents to deal with.  At a given level L ∈ { 0, 1, 2 }, there are 2^L processes, each of which forks 2 children which go on to work at level L+1.  The processes then identify themselves, wait for their children to die, and then report their own death.